# Any JQuery time plugin available to select Time on ASP.NET MVC Page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.NET Page on which the user need to select the TimeSlot like 10:00 AM PST, 10:15 AM PST.... etc at a constant interval of 15 Min (Flexible).

Using the JQuery datepicker, we can only select the date.

I am wondering if there is any readily JQuery plugin available for Timeslots as well?

Appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 4):

[jquery-timepicker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timepicker/) is decent - I used this plugin on a recent project.

Comment: Did that work for u. I am running into errors. All i did was, I have downloaded and added the reference in the Project and on my page. And I used the syntax ($('#TimeSlot').timepicker();) and I am getting some unknown errors.

Answer (score 2):

[JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) has a pretty good one too.

As an added bonus you get a custom theme for your website.  Then all of UI's components will have the same look and feel.

[Direct link to DataPicker control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual control? I do not believe timepicker is an official jQuery UI control at the moment.

Comment: @Justin - I don't have link to the actual control. Yes. As u mentioned, TimePicker is not official JQuery UI control. I tried to implement that using TimePicker but I am running into errors. Let me try one more time.

Answer (score 1):

- The easy thing is to use [jQuery Time Picker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timepicker/)

But I had some compatibility issues with jQuery Validator and jQuery TimePicker, hope you are not using both.

But if you do, i used this other plugin that forces the user to enter a maskered input

- [Masked Input jQuery Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

in fact i prefer this one, because you can continue filling the form without having to move your hand to the mouse to pick the desired time from a menu.

and I validated the time in jQuery with this custom rule

```
// custom rule for time fields
jQuery.validator.addMethod("time", function(value, element) {
    var hh = value.toString().substring(0, 2);
    var mm = value.toString().substr(3, 2);
    return this.optional(element) || ((parseFloat(hh) > 0 && parseFloat(hh) <= 12) && (parseFloat(mm) > 0 && parseFloat(mm) <= 59));
}, "Please enter a valid time");
```

**EDIT:** adding the round method to get 00, 15, 30, 45 minutes

```
$(".time").blur(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var hh = value.toString().substring(0, 2)
    var mm = parseFloat(value.toString().substr(3, 2));

    if (mm > 0 && mm <= 15) { $(this).val(hh+":15"); return; }
    if (mm > 15 && mm <= 30) { $(this).val(hh+":30"); return; }
    if (mm > 30 && mm <= 59) { $(this).val(hh+":45"); return; }

   $(this).val(hh+":45"); // if 00
});
```

Comment: I am wondering if we can limit the user to enter values for example 00, 15, 30, 45 in place of minutes.

Comment: you can write a jquery code that changes the user submitted field to the closest 15, 30, 45 adding a handler to the blur event, do you want me to write an example for you?